# Postgres Regex to escape dollar sign

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, postgresql

I'm using Rails/ActiveRecord/Postgres. Here is a sample test string I'm trying to match -

`:sample_data => "$$352054054640611,1010,2015/02/24,05:20:30,40.28370,-111.65530,1437.1,0,0,0,0,0.0,7,0.9,1010,0.0,12.2,8,1,0,81.3##"`

I only want to query for the first number after the first comma (ex: 1010). In Rails I was looking to do something like this.

```
number = "1010"
Model.where("sample_data ~* ?", "\$\$.*," + number + ",.*")
```

The problem is it looks like Postgres isn't allowing me to escape the two dollar signs like I hoped.

---

**Edit**

When I run `Model.where("sample_data ~* ?", "\$\$.*," + number + ",.*").to_sql`

I get -

```
"SELECT \"Model\".* FROM \"Model\"  WHERE (sample_data ~* '$$.*,1010,.*')"
```

Comment: Can you add the result of `Model.where("sample_data ~* ?", "\$\$.*," + number + ",.*").to_sql`

Comment: @max I updated my question with the result

Comment: Hmm, maybe you need to double escape? `Model.where("sample_data ~* ?", "\\$\\$.*," + number + ",.*")`

Comment: @max the double escapes work! The problem I'm having now is match the first set of digits - `Model.where("sample_data ~* ?", "\\$\\$(\\c+),1010,.*")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your *question* is, you need escape the backslashes. You're wanting to pass them in to Postgres, but Ruby is escaping the dollars instead. (It doesn't need to, because '$' isn't a special character in a Ruby string, but it'll let you do it anyway.)

```
Model.where("sample_data ~* ?", "\\$\\$.*," + number + ",.*").to_sql
```

The answer to your *problem* is, you probably don't need to specify the dollars at all. Try this:

```
Model.where("sample_data ~* ?", "^[^,]*,#{number}").to_sql
```

To help you interpret this regex:

- `^` = start of line
- `[^,]` = any character other than a comma
- `*` = zero to many times

This will also ensure that you don't find your number after a comma that *isn't* the first.